# Check if a matrix is in a dictionary list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matrix

I have a dictionary of lists in python and i want to check if a matrix is already in the dicionary.

```
C = {0: [matrix([[ 8.87155979,  2.50616085]]), matrix([[ 0.46289077,  8.05592104]])], 
     1: [matrix([[-1.3115368 ,  7.60922069]])], 
     2: [matrix([[ 0.46289077,  8.05592104]]), matrix([[-1.3115368 ,  7.60922069]]), matrix([[ 3.4826805 , -0.73544937]])]}
```

This input should return `true`: `[[ 8.87155979,  2.50616085]] in C`
How can i do that?

Comment: It is a numpy matrix.

Comment: @user3689757 - notes like that are better be embedded into the question itself, rather than just appear as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C= {0: [[[ 8.87155979, 2.50616085]],[[ 0.46289077, 8.05592104]]], 1: [[[-1.3115368 , 7.60922069]]]}

y = [[ 8.87155979,  2.50616085]]
print  any(y in x for x in C.values())# checks the subelements of the values in your dict
True
```

This  will work for your matrix as per your example.

```
y=[[ 0.46289077,  8.05592104]]

C = {0: [matrix([[ 8.87155979,  2.50616085]]), matrix([[ 0.46289077,  8.05592104]])],
     1: [matrix([[-1.3115368 ,  7.60922069]])],
     2: [matrix([[ 0.46289077,  8.05592104]]), matrix([[-1.3115368 ,  7.60922069]]), matrix([[ 3.4826805 , -0.73544937]])]}



 print any((y == x[0]).all() for x in C.values())
 True
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure matrix is numpy.matrix. With the OP's `C`, your solution throws `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.` for me.

Comment: It is a numpy.matrix as you said. The solution above didn't work for me.

Comment: the second code works for me using your exact same example code

Comment: @timgeb, well I am not a mind reader so from what the OP had provided when I answered it would not have taken too much to figure out the rest

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm getting this error:
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f928fd8c140>
What i'm missing there?

Comment: have you used  from numpy import * ? If you have don't, use import numpy as np and np.matrix etc... You have imported `numpy.any` using * syntax and  my code is using  python's `any`

Answer (score 1):

```
[[ 8.87155979, 2.50616085]] in [m.tolist() for lst in C.values() for m in lst]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it using two different ways: with and without list comprehension. *with* is the "python way", but it is up to your decision:

```
from numpy import *

C = {0: [matrix([[ 8.87155979,  2.50616085]]), matrix([[ 0.46289077,  8.05592104]])], 
     1: [matrix([[-1.3115368 ,  7.60922069]])], 
     2: [matrix([[ 0.46289077,  8.05592104]]), matrix([[-1.3115368 ,  7.60922069]]), matrix([[ 3.4826805 , -0.73544937]])]}

y = [[ 8.87155979, 2.50616085]]

# without list comprehension
for x in C.values():
    for m in x:
        if all(m==y):
            print(True)

# with list comprehension
print(any([all(m==y) for x in C.values() for m in x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine:

```
query = [[8.87155979, 2.50616085]]
any(query[0] in x[0] for x in C.values())
```